# Firestore increment value if document exists, otherwise set it

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to do an upsert with a firestore document like:

```
gameDb
        .collection("player-scores")
        .doc(playerId)
        .update({ score: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) });
```

If `playerId` document exists, then update the score, otherwise set it to 1.

If I do

```
gameDb
        .collection("player-scores")
        .doc(playerId)
        .set({ score: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) });
```

it works as I want for a moment and score is set to either `1` or the incremented value, but then the incremented score is overwritten by `1`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By using the `{merge: true}` [option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions?authuser=0#optional-merge) of the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference?authuser=0#set) method it will do the trick:

```
gameDb
        .collection("player-scores")
        .doc(playerId)
        .set({ score: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) }, {merge: true});
```

If the document does not exist, the field is initialized to 1, if it exists, it is incremented.